# How to get do calculations including date from datePicker in Xcode/

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to build a mortgage calculator for iPhone as a task and I need to be able to read startdate from DatePicker in MainView, then an enddate for another DatePicker in FlipView and calculate the difference in the number of months between both dates. As I am new to Apple programming I do not know how to do it. Help, please :)

Comment: @Abizern Not very far I am afraid. Just animated the pickers but no luck reading date from them for calculations

Comment: So, rather than a general "How do I write this app" question, the first thing you want to know is how to read a date from a date picker control.

Answer (score 0):

From your edit, it seems that the more specific problem you have is reading the date from a [UIDatePicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html)

From the docs, the method you need to call is `date`

```
NSDate *dateFromPicker = [myDatePickerObject date];
```

Comment: Can I do calculations on the date itself, that is subtract one date from the other to get the number of months (the difference between two dates)?

Comment: Again - The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtDates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000183-BCIDBADB) has the answers (See the section on basic date calculations).

Comment: Thanks again. I will study these more carefully. You are a great help.

Answer (score 0):

you could use - `(NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate` .

The result will be NSTimeInterval which will be a double that is equivalent to the amount of seconds.  Take that amount and divide by the appropriate number (seconds?  60. hours?  360. etc…)

The code would resemble:

```
[[datePicker1 date] timeIntervalSinceDate:[datePicker2 date]];
```

Good luck!

Comment: Not really - computers are good at these repetitive tasks, you just have to tell it what to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *differenceComponents = [calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0];
int monthDifference = differenceComponents.month;
```

Comment: Thanks i will try to put it in my project but it still needs a bit of work.

Comment: Sure, i suppose what you were looking for is the NSDateComponents type and the components fromdate:todate: method to get you started to implement your logic...